# showing UIView in main delegate over top all views

Tags: iphone

I have a UIView that is in my mainWindow.xib.

UIView *loadingView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *loadingView;

The view has a label and UIActivityIndicator on it, and I'm trying to use the view as a "Please wait, loading..." screen. Before I push a new view onto the stack, I call [window bringSubviewToFront:loadingView] from the main delegate. The new view is pushed onto the stack, and in the viewDidLoad method of the new view I load some data across the web. Once this data transfer completes, I am calling [window sendSubviewToBack:loadingView]; at the end of viewDidLoad method.

If I test it just calling the bringSubviewToFront method only, the view is placed on top of every other view, which is working as planned. I shortened the loadingView height so I can see the new view correctly load behind it. If I add the SendSubviewtoBack after all my web service calls have completed on the new view, the loadingView never becomes visible. Is this a threading issue, or logic issue? I'm not sure how to fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't quite understand what's wrong. What exactly does not work?
I mean, if everything works as planned, what are you trying to fix?

Comment: If I add the SendSubviewtoBack after all my web service calls have completed on the new view, the loadingView never becomes visible. Is this a threading issue, or logic issue? I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: To clarify: The view never shows when I put the sendSubviewToBack call at the end of the viewDidLoad method. If I leave it out, I see the new view load behind my mainWindow subview.

Comment: myAppDelegate *appDelegate = (myAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 [appDelegate startIndicator];
 
 StatsDateSelectController *selectcity = [[StatsDateSelectController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatsDateSelectController" bundle:nil]; 
 
 // Push the next form onto our stack
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:selectcity animated:NO];
 [selectcity release];

Comment: That is what I understood:
1. you call bringSubviewToFront => OK
2. you call bringSubviewToBack => OK
3. you call bringSubviewToFront => nothing happens.
is that right?